# Install Cpyrit on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I wanna install pyrit on my ubuntu 14.04. Firstly, I installed AMD APP SDK, CAL++, and my driver (fglrx_15.302-0ubuntu1_amd64_ub_14.01). I have problem on step

`sudo svn checkout http://pyrit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ pyrit_svn`

Error:

```
svn: E160013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://pyrit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
svn: E160013: '/svn/trunk' path not found
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is going to be the same as for other similar questions. None of the projects hosted on Google Code are now available. Hopefully the project was migrated to some other service by its maintainer.

Google Code is dead (closed) and it only offers minimal info about the projects. Thanks google! But you can get the latest version of the project's code at its page http://pyrit.googlecode.com/

The archive contains the Subversion working copy and its format is very outdated. I hope that you are using up-to-date Subversion client now and in such case you'll have to run `svn upgrade` command to make the working copy compatible with it. The working copy does not contain any changes history. Only the latest state is available.

Use the web search before asking such questions!